# Ios PWA launch screen doesnt change

Tags: html, ios, progressive-web-apps, splash-screen, launch

I am currently building PWA to my existing website.

When I add PWA to homescreen on IOS and launch is, no splashcreen is present. It is jsut white.

I have read a lot for now about making separate splashcreeens for all size devices for ios and done it in html of start_url as so:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#c28e1f">
    <!-- ios support -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/AppLogo1.png">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
    <!-- iPhone X (1125px x 2436px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="https://clicktoplay.ru/images/apple-launch-1125x2436.png">
<!-- iPhone 8, 7, 6s, 6 (750px x 1334px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="https://clicktoplay.ru/images/apple-launch-750x1334.png">
<!-- iPhone 8 Plus, 7 Plus, 6s Plus, 6 Plus (1242px x 2208px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/images/apple-launch-1242x2208.png">
<!-- iPhone 5 (640px x 1136px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="https://clicktoplay.ru/images/apple-launch-640x1136.png">
<!-- iPad Mini, Air (1536px x 2048px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="https://clicktoplay.ru/images/apple-launch-1536x2048.png">
<!-- iPad Pro 10.5" (1668px x 2224px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="https://clicktoplay.ru/images/apple-launch-1668x2224.png">
<!-- iPad Pro 12.9" (2048px x 2732px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="https://clicktoplay.ru/images/apple-launch-2048x2732.png">
```

But it just doenst work. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Someone please :'(((

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this - having the same issue..